# Using COleDispatchDriver to dynamically load COM object leaking memory

Tags: c#, c++, memory-leaks, com

I'm debugging some legacy code. It loads a user defined COM object, allows the user to call functions in it, and then releases it. However, we have found that every time we load and unload the COM object, we leak memory. As a test, we changed the code to load it and hang on to it, and keep re-using it until program exit and the leak went away.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

This C++ codeis is called to load the COM object, pszProgId is a string identifying the target DLL.

```
    COleDispatchDriver *pDispatchDriver = NULL;
    pDispatchDriver = new COleDispatchDriver();
    if (!pDispatchDriver->CreateDispatch(pszProgId, &oleException))
    {
     throw &oleException;
    }
    pDispatchDriver->m_bAutoRelease = TRUE;
   *ppvObject = (void *) pDispatchDriver;
```

void ** ppvObject is a pointer we pass around to generically hold different objects. It is part of a much larger structure.
And here is the code we call when releasing the COM object.

After we are done using the COM object, we release it as follows:

```
COleDispatchDriver* pDispatchDriver = (COleDispatchDriver*) (*((LONG_PTR*)(ppvObject)));
pDispatchDriver->ReleaseDispatch();
delete pDispatchDriver;
```

This is leaking about 1 meg every call. The target COM object is C#. Anyone have any idea what we're doing wrong or a better way to do what we're trying to do?

We are building this in VisualStudio 2015 in case that is relevant.

Re xMRi:

As already noted, we tried changing that flag to TRUE to no effect. As a sanity check, I tried doing that again after reading your post and again it did nothing to fix the memory leak. So for better clarity, I've updated my code to show it set to TRUE which is almost certainly the right value but still exhibiting the same memory leak described above.

Comment: C# code leaks memory by design.  The garbage collector runs when it has to, never because you release an interface pointer.  Write a unit test that executes this code a million times to gain confidence that your Release() calls are okay and to verify that you have a true memory leak that will crash your program.  You can observe what the GC does by looking at the .NET Memory perf counters in perfview.exe

Comment: We've run this through 5,000 iterations and the memory of the client program grew to about 5 gig. We had to kill it at that point but I'm pretty sure that was more than delayed garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

ReleaseDispatch does nothing if you set  `m_bAutoRelease` to FALSE. So in fact you don't free the instance of this COM object.

See the implementation:

```
void COleDispatchDriver::ReleaseDispatch()
{
    if (m_lpDispatch != NULL)
    {
        if (m_bAutoRelease)
            m_lpDispatch->Release();
        m_lpDispatch = NULL;
    }
}
```

So created the problem in setting `m_bAutoRelease` to `FALSE` yourself. Check the reasons why you are doing this.

You can directly get the `LPDISPTACH` pointer and call `Release()` but this is exactly what should be done when `m_bAutoRelease` is `TRUE`.